# TailwindCSS: Dynamic value for line-clamp is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, runtime

Good day guys, I am using React with TailwindCSS, and I'm trying to pass in a dynamic value for lineClamp like this:

`` <div className={`line-clamp-${lineClamp}`} ref={ref}>{longText}</div> ``

If I write this, it works:

```
<div
style={{
   overflow: 'hidden',
   display: '-webkit-box',
   WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
   WebkitLineClamp: lineClamp,
                }}
                ref={ref}
            >
                {longText}
            </div>
```

The problem I am encountering is, the line-clamp property only work occasionally.  But if I use inline style, it will work steadily. I wonder if the runtime of Tailwind cause the problem with webkit property.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using the `style` attribute like you have stated in your question.
- Using [`safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes):

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    // …
    safelist: [
      {
        pattern: /^line-clamp-(\d+)$/,
      },
    ],
    // …
  }
  ```